# PHP - syntax to escape a string for a link

Tags: escaping

I can't get the syntax for this quite right.

I have a line in a repeating table which works as it should, i.e. repeats the field 'Activity' from my query.

```
echo "<td width=\"18%\" align=\"left\">".$keyword['Activity']."</a></td>\n";
```

I am trying to make the Activity name a link to an update page:

```
<a href="../lodge_keyword_update/index.php?ActivityID=<?php echo(rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities['ActivityID'])); ?>">
```

The closest I seem to get is something like this:

```
echo "<td width=\"18%\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"../lodge_keyword_update/index.php?ActivityID=<?php echo(rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities['ActivityID'])); ?>\">".$keyword['Activity']."</a></td>\n";
```

But its not quite right - if someone could help out with the correct syntax that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
echo '<td width="18%" align="left"><a href="../lodge_keyword_update/index.php?ActivityID=' . rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities['ActivityID']) . '">' . $keyword['Activity'] . '</a></td>' . "\n";
```

When I need to echoes double quotes, I am always using single quote for delimiters, so I do not need to escape the double quotes.

Note

- I suggest to you to use an IDE to inspect syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much - that's working with that. And thanks for the other replies - I always appreciate this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
echo "<td width='18%' align='left'><a href='../lodge_keyword_update/index.php?ActivityID=".rawurlencode($row_WADAactivities['ActivityID']).">".$keyword['Activity']."</a></td>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<td width=\"18%\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"../lodge_keyword_update/index.php?ActivityID=<?php echo(rawurlencode(".$row_WADAactivities['ActivityID'].")); ?>\">".$keyword['Activity']."</a></td>\n";
```